# Sublime & Highlight: pasting as RTF fontsize issue

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, rtf, evernote, pygments

I downloaded a package named [SublimeHighlight](https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight) for the Sublime text editor. It serves as my solution to paste syntax highlighted code into Evernote. I have both Evernote and Sublime using the Menlo mono-spaced font. I select text in Sublime, right click and choose "copy as RTF". Pasting into Evernote retains the syntax coloring and indentation. So far so good.

In Evernote I have my default font size set to 14. No matter what my font size is set to in Sublime, when I paste into Evernote the font size is 12. I found [this page](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/?highlight=rtf) via google which shed a bit of light on the situation: pygments, used by SublimeHighlight, has a default font size of 12 (do a 'find' on the page for 'fontsize' and you'll see it). The problem is I don't know python (what pygments *and* SublimeHighlight are written in) and have no idea how to change the font size of pasted-in text from Sublime to Evernote.

All I'm looking for is to past syntax highlighted code from **Sublime** into Evernote at the correct font size.

---

**EDIT:**
I just downloaded [Atom](https://atom.io/) and a package for it called [Copy as RTF](https://atom.io/packages/copy-as-rtf). It works flawless. I really wanted to stay within the Sublime ecosystem, but Atom just works. Plus, *Copy as RTF* for Atom has more recent updates than *SublimeHightlight* for Sublime. Whatever works, right?

Comment: So you question is to find a tool that can past syntax highlighted code into Everntoe with the correct font size, no matter the tool is sublime or not, right?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to use `UltraEdit`, which can help you copy your code as **RTF** or **HTML** and paste them into Evernote.

[image: Use <code>Copy Special</code>]

and then

[image: Copy Code to Evernote]

More details can be found [here](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/copy-paste-syntax-highlighting.html)

Or you can try `Notepad++` and use the **NppExport** plugin.

[image: Notepad NppExport]

and change the font size you want in Words or Outlook

[image: RTF Open]

Check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/578054/how-can-i-copy-text-with-syntax-highlighting-from-notepad) for more detail

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for bringing those options to my attention. I'm hoping to stay within the Sublime ecosystem. If other answers don't persist, then I'll look into a different text editor and review your options. Thanks!